# How to extract the number of users who logged on for two consecutive months

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to pull number of users who logged on the app for two consecutive months using postgresql and list the results as

```
Month    NBR_USERS
JAN      users who logged on in Dec 2016 as well as Jan 2017
FEB      users who logged on in Jan 2017 and Feb 2017
MAR      users who logged on in Feb 2017 and Mar 2017
```

Comment: Great!  Do you have any tables to provide such data?  What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by summarizing the data by user and month and then aggregating again by month:

```
select to_char(yyyymm, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm, count(*) as num_users       
from (select userid, date_trunc('month', visitdate) as visitmonth,
             lag(date_trunc('month', visitdate)) over (partition by userid order by date_trunc('month', visitdate)) as prev_visitmonth
      from t
      group by userid, visitmonth
     ) t
where prev_visitmonth = visitmonth - interval '1 month'
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```